# how to pass month and year (ex: Mar-19) in DATESBETWEEN function in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am following an example of building KPI matrix from YouTube.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sq4oRnCGUAE&t=66s

How they passing `Calendar[Month & Year]` column in `DATESBETWEEN` function??

```
DATESBETWEEN(<dates>,<start_date>,<end_date>)
```

Isn't it first parameter has to be always type `date`?

[image]

My goal is to create 6 months trend, but for some reason dax expression does not work:

```
WP 6M TrendTest = 
VAR LastEffDate = LASTDATE(fact_Premium[EffectiveDate])
RETURN 
AVERAGEX(
DATESBETWEEN(
        dim_Date[Date],
        DATEADD(LastEffDate, - 5, MONTH), //creates rolling 6 months window and then takes average on [Mom WP] which is  difference between [Ttl WP] and [PreviousMonthWP] and only using months with values.
        ENDOFMONTH(LastEffDate)
        ),
        [Ttl WP]
)
```

The result I expect is to take average on grouped `Month Over Month` column for the last 6 months

[image]

Comment: Whcih minute you are looking at in the video? Seems to me [Month & Year] is the name of the date field they used. Can you give us some raw data and the end result you expect?

Comment: it is on 30:39 . They calculating 6M trend column

Comment: More straightforward would be `DATESINPERIOD` there.